# How to point domain to same host?

Tags: dns, web-hosting

I have:

```
mydomain.com
www.mydomain.com
www.myotherdomain.com
```

All pointing to the one web host and everything works. `www.myotherdomain.com` is served by a folder: `myotherdomain` on the host.

How can I point:

```
myotherdomain.com
```

To the same folder serving `www.myotherdomain.com`?

Answer (score 0):

Use a 301 redirect.

Look for the best implementation based on your tech:
http://www.webconfs.com/how-to-redirect-a-webpage.php

Answer (score 0):

You can add ".htaccess" file to your website folder (e.g /var/www/html) and add the followings

```
# For sites running on a port other than 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^80$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://www.example.com:%{SERVER_PORT}/$1 [L,R]

# And for a site running on port 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R]
```

for more information please visit [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html).